# How to install Elasticsearch and Kibana into Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

**How to install Elasticsearch and Kibana into Ubuntu 14.04?**

```
 wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.2.2.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow this installation instructions.
 [try this](//www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/elasticsearch-and-kibana-installation-and-basic-usage-on-ubuntu-1604/)

OR 
use

https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana

Comment: I would like to import it using logstash. Over the internet I end up with following config:

 input {
     file {
  path => ["simpsons_episodes.csv"]
  start_position => "beginning"
     }
 }

 filter {
     csv {
  columns => [
      "id",
      "title"
  ]
     }
 }

 output {
     stdout { codec => rubydebug }
     elasticsearch {
  action => "index"
  hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
  index => "simpsons"
  document_type => "episode"
  workers => 1
     }
 }

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions, especially not with a link-only answer.  Please read [answer]